# Is there a way to implement a circular waiting indicator using PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qwidget

I am trying to build an application using PyQt. A part of the application runs a thread which takes some time to complete. How can I add a waiting indicator (preferably circular) to indicate running of the process?

I know I can go with a progress bar, or perhaps a splash screen. I have looked into both but I am trying to opt for one of them only as a last resort. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-busyindicator.html) or [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Busy_Indicator_for_QML)?

Comment: Oh Great! Thank you @ArnavBorborah. Is there a way I can do the same in Python? I found one [implementation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/A%20full%20widget%20waiting%20indicator) but I guess it requires some event. I am not able to get it to work with any other condition that changes inside the program. Sorry if this sounds trivial. I have a very think experience with PyQt

Comment: If you are asking how to integrate the QML, there are numerous tutorials online, such as [this one](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qml.html) or [this one](https://pythonspot.com/qml-and-pyqt-creating-a-gui-tutorial/).

Comment: Is there a way to do it using the standard PyQt library?

Comment: I'm sorry; I wouldn't be able to answer that since I am not as experienced. For whatever I said before, it was a quick Google search that aided me.

Comment: If you do not know about QML I recommend you not to use it, you will waste a lot of time trying to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have converted the code from the [QtWaitingSpinner](https://github.com/snowwlex/QtWaitingSpinner) from C ++ to PyQt4/PyQt5

```
from math import ceil

"""from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *"""

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class QtWaitingSpinner(QWidget):
    mColor = QColor(Qt.gray)
    mRoundness = 100.0
    mMinimumTrailOpacity = 31.4159265358979323846
    mTrailFadePercentage = 50.0
    mRevolutionsPerSecond = 1.57079632679489661923
    mNumberOfLines = 20
    mLineLength = 10
    mLineWidth = 2
    mInnerRadius = 20
    mCurrentCounter = 0
    mIsSpinning = False

    def __init__(self, centerOnParent=True, disableParentWhenSpinning=True, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.mCenterOnParent = centerOnParent
        self.mDisableParentWhenSpinning = disableParentWhenSpinning
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.rotate)
        self.updateSize()
        self.updateTimer()
        self.hide()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def rotate(self):
        self.mCurrentCounter += 1
        if self.mCurrentCounter > self.numberOfLines():
            self.mCurrentCounter = 0
        self.update()

    def updateSize(self):
        size = (self.mInnerRadius + self.mLineLength) * 2
        self.setFixedSize(size, size)

    def updateTimer(self):
        self.timer.setInterval(1000 / (self.mNumberOfLines * self.mRevolutionsPerSecond))

    def updatePosition(self):
        if self.parentWidget() and self.mCenterOnParent:
            self.move(self.parentWidget().width() / 2 - self.width() / 2,
                      self.parentWidget().height() / 2 - self.height() / 2)

    def lineCountDistanceFromPrimary(self, current, primary, totalNrOfLines):
        distance = primary - current
        if distance < 0:
            distance += totalNrOfLines
        return distance

    def currentLineColor(self, countDistance, totalNrOfLines, trailFadePerc, minOpacity, color):
        if countDistance == 0:
            return color

        minAlphaF = minOpacity / 100.0

        distanceThreshold = ceil((totalNrOfLines - 1) * trailFadePerc / 100.0)
        if countDistance > distanceThreshold:
            color.setAlphaF(minAlphaF)

        else:
            alphaDiff = self.mColor.alphaF() - minAlphaF
            gradient = alphaDiff / distanceThreshold + 1.0
            resultAlpha = color.alphaF() - gradient * countDistance
            resultAlpha = min(1.0, max(0.0, resultAlpha))
            color.setAlphaF(resultAlpha)
        return color

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.updatePosition()
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), Qt.transparent)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        if self.mCurrentCounter > self.mNumberOfLines:
            self.mCurrentCounter = 0
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        for i in range(self.mNumberOfLines):
            painter.save()
            painter.translate(self.mInnerRadius + self.mLineLength,
                              self.mInnerRadius + self.mLineLength)
            rotateAngle = 360.0 * i / self.mNumberOfLines
            painter.rotate(rotateAngle)
            painter.translate(self.mInnerRadius, 0)
            distance = self.lineCountDistanceFromPrimary(i, self.mCurrentCounter,
                                                         self.mNumberOfLines)
            color = self.currentLineColor(distance, self.mNumberOfLines,
                                          self.mTrailFadePercentage, self.mMinimumTrailOpacity, self.mColor)
            painter.setBrush(color)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(QRect(0, -self.mLineWidth // 2, self.mLineLength, self.mLineLength),
                                    self.mRoundness, Qt.RelativeSize)
            painter.restore()

    def start(self):
        self.updatePosition()
        self.mIsSpinning = True
        self.show()

        if self.parentWidget() and self.mDisableParentWhenSpinning:
            self.parentWidget().setEnabled(False)

        if not self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.start()
            self.mCurrentCounter = 0

    def stop(self):
        self.mIsSpinning = False
        self.hide()

        if self.parentWidget() and self.mDisableParentWhenSpinning:
            self.parentWidget().setEnabled(True)

        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.stop()
            self.mCurrentCounter = 0

    def setNumberOfLines(self, lines):
        self.mNumberOfLines = lines
        self.updateTimer()

    def setLineLength(self, length):
        self.mLineLength = length
        self.updateSize()

    def setLineWidth(self, width):
        self.mLineWidth = width
        self.updateSize()

    def setInnerRadius(self, radius):
        self.mInnerRadius = radius
        self.updateSize()

    def color(self):
        return self.mColor

    def roundness(self):
        return self.mRoundness

    def minimumTrailOpacity(self):
        return self.mMinimumTrailOpacity

    def trailFadePercentage(self):
        return self.mTrailFadePercentage

    def revolutionsPersSecond(self):
        return self.mRevolutionsPerSecond

    def numberOfLines(self):
        return self.mNumberOfLines

    def lineLength(self):
        return self.mLineLength

    def lineWidth(self):
        return self.mLineWidth

    def innerRadius(self):
        return self.mInnerRadius

    def isSpinning(self):
        return self.mIsSpinning

    def setRoundness(self, roundness):
        self.mRoundness = min(0.0, max(100, roundness))

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.mColor = color

    def setRevolutionsPerSecond(self, revolutionsPerSecond):
        self.mRevolutionsPerSecond = revolutionsPerSecond
        self.updateTimer()

    def setTrailFadePercentage(self, trail):
        self.mTrailFadePercentage = trail

    def setMinimumTrailOpacity(self, minimumTrailOpacity):
        self.mMinimumTrailOpacity = minimumTrailOpacity


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dial = QDialog()
    w = QtWaitingSpinner(dial)
    dial.show()
    w.start()
    QTimer.singleShot(1000, w.stop)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/1a09157d17ba13d223c312b28a81c320) you can find a complete example

Comment: Thanks a lot, @eyllanesc. It worked like a charm. QPainter seems great. I just got a reason to dabble in it. :)

Comment: `drawRoundedRect` takes two radius arguments (in the current version at least) - So instead of `self.mRoundness, Qt.RelativeSize)` it would be `self.mRoundness, self.mRoundness, Qt.RelativeSize)`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above response...

If you are using Qt Designer you'll need to create a QWidget and promote it to a QtWaitingSpinner. You can follow [this](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/qt-creator/embed-pyqtgraph-custom-widgets-qt-app/) for promoting QWidgets. In this case, your Promoted Class name is QtWaitingSpinner and Header file is the file where the QtWaitingSpinner class is located.

[image]

Once your GUI is set you can call

```
your_QtWaitingSpinnerObject.start()
```