# Displaying Gif Loading in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to display a loading gif while other code executes. I am very unfamiliar with PyQt and have tried following the code at [this](https://www.unlogic.co.uk/2012/11/02/show-animated-gifs-using-pyqt/) link, which seems to be the standard way of executing a gif. I only want the gif playing and do not want a button. Here is the code I am currently at, but it is very poor.

```
self.movie = QMovie(coffeeloading.gif, self)
size = self.movie.scaledSize()
self.movie_screen.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
self.movie_screen.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
self.movie_screen = QLabel()
main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
main_layout.addWidget(self.movie_screen)
self.setLayout(main_layout)
self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
self.movie.setSpeed(100)
self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
self.movie.start()
```

This is supposed to execute after a button press and fill up the whole screen of 240x320, but I dont have any idea how to do it. I have already read through many of the other stackoverflow and other links, but none of them seem to address how to complete this.

Comment: What is the problem? The blog code does what you want.

Comment: Running this code I get that coffeeloading, which is my gif, is not defined and when I give the full directory in quotes I get this error: TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QMovie(parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  QMovie(QIODevice, format: QByteArray = QByteArray(), parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  QMovie(object, format: QByteArray = QByteArray(), parent: QObject = None): argument 2 has unexpected type 'MainWindow'

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use [this](https://github.com/z3ntu/QtWaitingSpinner) class here.

QtWaitingSpinner extends the QtWidgets.QWidget class and you can start your spinner by simply running

```
your_QtWaitingSpinnerObject.start()
```

[image]

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441863/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-circular-waiting-indicator-using-pyqt/63206398#63206398) answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class test_widget(QWidget):

    m_play_state = False
    def __init__(self):
        super(test_widget, self).__init__()
        self.__ui__()

    def __ui__(self):

        t_lay_parent = QVBoxLayout()
        self.m_label_gif = QLabel()

        self.m_button_play = QPushButton("Play")
        t_lay_parent.addWidget(self.m_label_gif)
        t_lay_parent.addWidget(self.m_button_play)

        self.m_movie_gif = QMovie("loding.gif")
        self.m_label_gif.setMovie(self.m_movie_gif)
        self.m_label_gif.setScaledContents(True)
        self.m_label_gif.hide()

        self.setLayout(t_lay_parent)
        self.m_button_play.clicked.connect(self.slt_play)

    def slt_play(self):
        if self.m_play_state:
            self.m_label_gif.hide()
            self.m_movie_gif.stop()
            self.m_play_state = False
        else:
           self.m_label_gif.show()
           self.m_movie_gif.start()
           self.m_play_state = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = test_widget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```